# Python 3.5: List comprehension for a matrix with a given density?

Tags: python, list, matrix

I would like to make an n x n matrix of boolean values (0 or 1) with a given density d (percent of non-zero entries). I believe one can do this with the random module and list comprehension.

For this question lets not consider sci.py or num.py

To make a list of lists:

```
import random
n = 5
[[random.randint(0,1) for column in range(n)] for row in range(n)]

[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1], 
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 0], 
 [0, 1, 0, 1, 1], 
 [1, 1, 1, 0, 0], 
 [0, 1, 1, 0, 0]]
```

and we have a matrix. The problem is the density will always be ≈ .5

So how do we change the inner list comprehension to give us the value one with a probability equivalent to the density?

```
[[0 if <condition> else 1 for column in range(n)] for row in range(n)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest `0 if random.random() >  d else 1`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`random.random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.random) to return `float` between `0.0` and `1.0`:

```
>>> import random
>>> import pprint
>>> m = [[0 if random.random() < 0.3 else 1 for _ in range(5)] for _ in range(5)]
>>> pprint.pprint(m)
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: this is for a density  0.7